# How do I create a DataTable variable that is accessible by every method on the page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable, scope

I am new to ASP.NET C#.
I would like to create a DataTable that persists and is accessible by every method on the page. A listview control binds to the datatable so when the user adds a row to teh DataTable, it is displayed in the ListView.
I would like the DataTable to persist until the user navigates away from the page (or F5 refresh).
It is important that each user must have their own instance of the DataTable, so the ListView displays only the rows of that user and not other users.
I tried declaring a static variable as follows:

```
namespace MySite
{
    public partial class MyPage: System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        public static DataTable dtbMyDataTable = new DataTable();
```

But I subsequently found out that static variables like this persist for the lifetime of the app domain. Also different users don't get their own instance of the datatable, so each user is accessing the same datatable and can see everyone's data in the ListView.

I also tried declaring a field as follows:

```
    public static DataTable dtbMyDataTable { set; get; }
```

But this produced the same problem of users not having their own instance of the DataTable, so each user can see other users' data in the ListView, which is not good.

Another idea I had was to create the DataTable in Page_Load and then store it as a session variable so the data in the DataTable can be accessed by other methods when required. This also solves the problem of users only accessing their own data. The problem with this is that the session will timeout and the user will lose their data if they are away from their computer for a while.

All suggestions greatly appreciated. I have spent a lot of time googling this and come up empty-handed.

I am new to Stack Overflow so forgive me if I have not formatted this question correctly.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Any field can be accessed by other methods in the class. Can you add more detail to your question, please?

Comment: It's a web app. Managing state is a bit of an art. Putting it in session can be the way to go, but don't rely on it always being there (how, for example do you plan on knowing that the user has navigated from the page, or, just closed the browser tab). You need to design how you plan on managing users, their authentication/authorization, their sessions and their state. If you load balance across multiple servers, it gets even more interesting

Comment: Seems like you're trying to get the server to remember too much; it's not supposed to be that the server itself keeps huge amount of user data separately for each concurrent user, for hours on end. You should be more thinking of tracking a user id, keeping the user data somewhere else (database), load it and give it to them when they want it, accept updates from them (or an auto save routine pushing tiny bits back regularly) when they want to save it, and patching it into your data store..

Comment: Might also be worth pointing out that you seem to be developing a web forms app, which is at least a couple of generations behind Microsoft's current focus of web tech  (it was followed by MVC and now Blazor) - do you really want to use it for new dev?

Comment: @CaiusJard, both good points. Maybe I'll try to minimise server load by saving the user data as CSV in a hidden field, rather than storing the DataTables in session variables. I'm trying to avoid storing data in databases (for several reasons) and I'm trying to avoid user authentication. The web app Just requires some user input to produce a quick form. I should probably look into Blazor too, I had no idea webforms was effectively deprecated - I'm just a hobbyist and webforms is all I know :-(

Comment: Conceptually that's all webforms does with your page data - you propose to put a csv in a hidden field, it puts a datatable in the viewstate- it all gets shuttled back and forth and restored at each end (but your csv idea does it manually) so there's still this notion that "the data has to be stored somewhere" - it's either in the session in the server, in the data transiting across the inter tubes or it's in the client.. or you pull some tricks to minimize as much as possible, leave most of it in the db and send bits around with Json/xhr which is the modern way.. kinda like 80s mainframes :)

Answer (score 1):

You just have to mantain the declaration of the variable in the bigger scope, but load the values within the Page_Load, and check if it is a postback:

```
namespace MySite
{
    public partial class MyPage: System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        public static DataTable dtbMyDataTable = new DataTable();

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           if (!IsPostBack)
           {
            dtbMyDataTable = LoadData(userID);
           }
           else
           {
              //process submitted values by the user here
           }
      }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Gabriel. I have a method where the user manually adds rows to the DataTable, but unfortunately declaring the DataTable in the bigger scope means that the ListView will show the data entered by all users, not that specific user..

Comment: You probably can do the same cycle using Session, worth a try

Answer (score 1):

Well, as you note, a listview, gridview etc. can be filled with a data table. And you can loop/interate the gridview. However, your table?

You have to persit it yourself. There are seveal ways to do this.

If the table is small (say only 50-100 rows), then it is reasonble to save that table. You can place the table in session() (server side storage - per user).

Or you can use ViewState. This is per browser page.

So, you often see say this:

```
public class HotelEdit : System.Web.UI.Page
{
private DataTable MyTable;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    if (System.Web.UI.Page.IsPostBack == false)
        LoadGrid();
    else
        MyTable = System.Web.UI.Page.Session["MyTable"];
}

public void LoadGrid()
{
    using (SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand("SELECT * from tblHotels ORDER by HotelName", new SqlConnection(My.Settings.Test3)))
    {
        cmdSQL.Connection.Open();
        MyTable.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader);
        ListView1.DataSource = MyTable;
        ListView1.DataBind();
    }

    System.Web.UI.Page.Session["MyTable"] = MyTable;
}

protected void cmdEdit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button btn = sender;
    int RowID = btn.Attributes.Item("RowID");

    RowEdit(RowID);
}

public void RowEdit(int RowID)
{
    HotelList.Style("display") = "none";
    MyRedit.Style("display") = "normal";

    fLoader(MyRedit, MyTable.Rows(RowID));
}
}
```

So, when I click on a grid row, the button runs RowEdit - note how I pass to a routine called fLoader (its a editor routine) the row the user selected - and I use the "MyTable" that is scoped to the whole form.

As noted, in most cases, you will often do a table re-load, but for a "smallish" table, then you can persist the data table as per above, and have use of it in all events and code in that page.